# Positive/Neutral score, but keep losing

Tags: league-of-legends

My biggest losing streak was a 8 lose streak and recently I had another 3 lose streak.

In ALL of these games, my score was either neutral or positive, but NEVER negative. However, in all of them, there was always at LEAST one person on a ridiculously low score (for example in my most recent game, the adc went 1/11).

I feel that I am a lot more knowledgeable than many of my team mates (I don't mean this in an arrogant way but many of them don't seem to know basics like objectives > kills, taking a drag after killing both in bot lane at level 6, backing off once taking inhibitor and on low HP, not chasing, warding the right places, don't try to duel a Jax, don't try to split push unless the rest of the team is taking another objective simultaneously, etc)

Now I'm aware that I'm not a perfect player, I make mistakes and in every single game, there is ALWAYS something I could have done better. However, I don't often get caught out or say push a lane with no vision etc. The mistakes I usually make are things like forgetting that I have a smite charge to use in a team fight, forgetting to use Face of the Mountain on my adc when duelling their bot lane, forgetting that I have a potion leftover and not using it when that could have saved me.

However, I feel very demotivated at the moment to continue playing ranked games. I don't mind losing a game here and there because of a ridiculously low scoring member of the team, since that just happens sometimes, but when this happens so many times in a row, it does make ranked feel much less enjoyable for me because I feel 'helpless'. My most recent example of something like this was when I was 24/3 and the rest of my team mates were around 3/12, 0/9, 1/11 etc. That game I still lost.

I often see people saying that if I belong in a certain tier, then I'll get there eventually after some number of games, but I'm starting to believe this less and less the more of these kinds of games I play.

Is this normal and do you perhaps have any suggestions? Am I just seeing things the wrong way? I play either top, jungle or support. I am almost always either jungle or support though.

Comment: Can you include a link to a match history, for example when you went 24/3 and lost?

Comment: Try building a team. Get 5 friends to help you out and use a third party voice chat system. Assuming ranked play allows parties of 5. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To me it sounds like you're trying to play a team game solo. Who cares if you're 50/0 if you're not helping THE TEAM. Don't put so much focus on the scores, focus on benefiting your team even if it means you go 2/10.

Also follow your team, even if you think they're doing the wrong thing. It's better for everyone to do the same wrong thing then for 1 person to do the wrong thing while the rest do the right thing.

Going 24/3 doesn't really help your team that much, let others get the final hit if you can. Obviously it depends on your champion/role but it's usually better to share the gold around, if you're super fed while the rest of your team isn't then the enemy are just going to focus you in that final team fight then push to win.

Remember if there's at least one person getting an assist on a kill your team gets 150% of the gold than it would've if there wasn't an assist. So with all these kills you're getting are you just hunting down enemies by yourself, or are you going with your teammates to get the kill together?

If you see one of your teammates/lanes are doing badly as you mentioned. Before they get to to 1/11 stage, help them out. Roam around a bit and gank their lane. Sometimes it's impossible to win a lane without outside help. So if you notice someone struggling, go help them out, if you help them get a kill it's unlikely the enemy will continue to snowball, it might even turn it around and let your struggling teammate to snowball instead. Even if you don't get the kill but manage to get the enemy champion out of lane. This will help your teammate tremendously; it will give them time to farm a little bit of gold and XP which may be the difference they need to be able to compete with their lane opponent.

Comment: Sometimes a lane is a lost cause, in that case helping the other lane get ahead is the only thing you can do.

Comment: I think this is the general problem with bronze/silver players that have good laning - they think their KDR/KDA actually matters. Being positive or negative doesn't matter, winning the game does. It's all about objective control, and being aware of your teammates when they are struggling.

Comment: @GarrettJ yeah, you'll find that damage dealt to enemy champions is a far better indicator of how well someone performed. I'm quite confidant that OP didn't have an exceedingly high damage to champs even with his good scores.

Comment: @Aequitas For the damage, it depends. When someone has a poking champion, it tends to increase a lot the damage done, but it doesn't improve their usefulness.

Comment: @dyesdyes yes that's why i said it's a "better indicator". There's no perfect stat to tell how well someone went in any particular game, the only way would be to watch the replay (and even then I'm sure people would disagree). But I've found that dmg to champs is the most accurate stat in determining how useful, or well someone did, but yes, it always depends and is never always accurate.

Answer (score 4):

I can understand your frustration. Here are few points.

**Lose streak and win streak**

You might have had your worst losing streak, but don't you also have winning streak? Where everything seems to easy? Where although you have a neutral score, your team completely stomps on the other team?

I bet you do, and if you don't think you do, then you should pay more attention. We tend to blame others when we lose, but think of it as normal when we win. In fact, when you win, you will most of the time think that you deserved it etc, even if you didn't do great.

**Team game**

As mentioned in other responses, it's a team game. And having a positive/neutral score might be nice for the stats, but that doesn't say anything about how well you did. You can have 8/2/4, but you only last hit and don't do much damage in Team fights etc.

Don't worry much about your stats. If you have to die for someone to have a double kill (even if you dont get the assists), then it is definitely worth it (if he is a carry).

Follow the team even if the engage is bad. Bad engage + 4 V 5 is for sure a complete slaughter. Bad engage + 5v5, at least you might kill few of them and make them low enough so they can't nashor etc.

**Carry Hard**

Ok, so your teammates are feeding hard, not much you can do, you can try to gank etc but you are not god. It happens.

What happened? Someone against you is carrying really hard. Stop thinking that your teammate is super bad because he feeds, maybe the guy against him is just really good, you might have not done better yourself. And once you are at 0/5, you make even more mistakes because you are desperate (hence the drake not taken etc. poor decision because too frustrated to think straight).

But if your teammate who fed has the same elo as you, there is a reason. Maybe he is the kind of player who carries really hard or feeds really hard (yes it exists).

Anyway, the issue is that, except if you carry really hard a game and lose (like it happened to you, in this case, really, you can't do anything, except trying to share more the gold). If you don't carry often, then it means you are supposed to stay at your elo. That might be sad to say, but you won't get higher in elo by having only slightly positive score or neutral score. You need to carry hard.

**Take a break**

This is important. You see you have 3-4 loses in a row. Just take a break, few hours, few days. And when you are happy to play again, play a rank game, not before. If you are not going to have fun, and you take it too seriously, you are not going to enjoy it and thus make more mistakes etc. It's a game after all right? Just have fun.

Answer (score 2):

Such streaks are statistically *bound* to happen.

There are many LoL players ; a consequence is that there are many *bad* players. There is a high probability that in every game you play, there will be at least one of them, and that he will be in your team.

Score is not that important, as you know ; what matters is **teamplay**. And it can be hard to achieve with randoms.

---

Final advice : if you don't enjoy a game anymore, take a break from it. Really. And as for LoL, it is much more enjoyable with friends to play with.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try out so you raise your elo in this case:

- Play champs with who you can carry hard, so it doesn't matter when an other player is extremely bad/an enemy is fed
- Play duoQ, so the number of potential feeder is decreased
- Buy wards for yourself and your teammates and ping them if you see they are overextending
- Try to shotcall as good as possible in the chat; your mates won't always follow them, but when you make good calls they can win you the game
- never flame, try to prevent the others from flaming
- continue playing: statistically the enemy team has as often feeder as your team has, so the more you play, the better you get and the number of feeder should equal out
- and the final advice: score doesn't win you the game, an afk isn't negative too, so just don't be afraid to make plays and go aggressive (if your champion is made for this)

Comment: DuoQ I disagree with unless you practice together, use voice comms, etc. It gives you a matchmaking penalty to compensate for the duo q advantage....